# Using ttk.button to toggle state of GPIO pin

Tags: python

How can I use one `ttk.button` to toggle state of `GPIO` pin in Raspberry.
Here below is part of the code which `ttk.button` is calling: ttk.button
(command=callback13)

Function is setting a pin 18 to `False` but by pressing it again
nothing is happening. Could anybody help me to sort this mystery? I'm
very new to programming in Python and would really appreciate it.

```
global B1
B1 = bool
B1 = True
def callback13():
    if B1==True:
        callback3()
    else:
    callback4()
def callback3():
    GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(18, False)
    B1=False
def callback4():
    GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(18, True)
    B1=True
```